# Unexpected BundleConfig behaviour

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

ASPNET MVC5 Web application

I keep getting unexpected results by implementing BundleConfig.

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

 public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundlejquery").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.min.js"));
   

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

Here's a view containing a carousel: I get different css output depending on using or not BundleConfig.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.csss" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/StepBar.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-themes-1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundlejquery")
</head>
```

Output (as expected, carousel img is horizontally centered)

[image]

Now I simply REM first 4 links and Un-REM @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.csss" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css" />*@
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/StepBar.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-themes-1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundlejquery")
</head>
```

I am not expecting a change in html output as I only have substituted those 4 stylesheets with their reference in the BundleConfig class.
Nevertheless the output is somewhat different:

[image]

Now carousel pictures are left aligned.
That means the substitution was NOT equivalent to the 4 original stylesheets: how can it be?

Comment: Is `~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.*csss*` just a typo on your part?

Comment: It is, in any case that does not account for shifted carousel images. I am actually developing on a 24" screen. Also note the correctly working version (centered carousel image) is that with the non-influential typo;)